# typo3 9.5.14 Installation fails

Tags: typo3

The installation of typo3 9.5.14 always fails (see also: http://www.typo3forum.net/discussion/84199/typo3-9-5-14-installation-mit-symlinks-scheitert).
The “installing tool” always stops at the last point, “Create Administrative User”. (has nothing to do with symlinks ...). Logging into the backend is not possible, not even into the InstallTool. In LocalConfiguration.php: 'installToolPassword' => 'xy', is missing .
Will the next version 9.5.15. be easyer to install?

Comment: On which system (OS, PHP version, web server type, database type) did you try to install? Did you find any error messages in the log files? Since you mentioned the password properties are not assigned, I guess crypto-graphic hashing modules (like Argon2i) are not available on your system.

Answer (score 0):

I've got some Warnings for Apache:

> Warning    AH01909: RSA certificate configured for domain.ch:443 does
>   NOT include an ID which matches the server name

and Errors:

> Error 80.74.144.144   AH01276: Cannot serve directory
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/domain.ch/httpdocs/: No matching DirectoryIndex
>   (index.php,index.html,index.shtml,index.htm,index.cgi,index.pl,index.xhtml)
>   found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options
>   directive
>   * Error   178.193.43.69   POST /typo3/install.php HTTP/1.0
>   * Error   178.193.43.69   POST /typo3/install.php?install[controller]=settings HTTP/1.0
>   *Error    80.74.144.144   GET / HTTP/1.0
>   *Error    80.74.144.144   GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0
>   *Error    178.193.43.69   POST /typo3/install.php?install[controller]=maintenance HTTP/1.0
>   *Error    178.193.43.69   GET /typo3/install.php?install[controller]=layout&install[action]=executeSilentConfigurationUpdate&_=1585158409375
>   HTTP/1.0
>   *

Argon2 ist not running on the Server. Could Typo3 9.5 also installed without Argon2